# Can't block touchpad on a Toshiba c660

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I recently updated to ubuntu 12.04 and I can't enable/disable my laptop touchpad. 
It's a bug ?

I have a Toshiba c660 . I block my touchpad with FN + F9. In ubuntu 11.04 worked. I guess that, since ubuntu 11.10 stopped working (I didn't try to block my touchpad in ubuntu 11.10 cause I had it for 3 days) .

Comment: Can you provide details about your notebook? How do you usually block your touchpad on that notebook? Is there a special key to do it? (i.e. my DELL XPS 15 has a special key that disables the touchpad and I guess that's an OS independent hardware feature)

Comment: I have a Toshiba c660 . I block my touchpad with FN + F9. In ubuntu 11.04 worked. I guess that, since ubuntu 11.10 stopped working ( i didn`t tried to block my touchpad in ubuntu 11.10 `cause i had it for 3 days ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an application called `touchpad-indicator` to enable aqnd disable the touchpad on laptops where t he function key has stopped working. Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt+ T) and type the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Then run the program by opening up the unity dash and searching for "touchpad". You can then enable and disable the touchpad from the icon in your notification area or set a keyboard shortcut to enable and disable the touchpad: 
[image]
Hope that helps!

Comment: thanx ! it worked ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get gpointing-device-settings without adding a new ppa's to your system. Its available from Ubuntu's repo.

It works just like touchpad-indicator and allows you to disable the touchpad.